# object change notifications are delivered many minutes later than the file is uploaded

Tags: google-cloud-storage

When uploading files to google cloud storage using resumable upload and getting 2xx code after the final chunk had been uploaded sometimes it takes a few seconds to get a notification and sometimes they are delayed for as much as 40! minutes. This is extremely unpredictable and leads to poor user experience.

Could some1 help me and explain what I could be doing wrong?

Example of response to hook (I do accept them properly with 2xx status codes)

`{
  "name": "core-api",
  "hostname": "http-in-production-0",
  "pid": 1,
  "namespace": "audit",
  "audit": true,
  "level": 30,
  "remoteAddress": "10.240.0.6",
  "remotePort": 36689,
  "req_id": "6feb5f2a-82aa-4d24-b844-2db915868fd3",
  "req": {
    "query": {},
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "/api/files/gce",
    "headers": {
      "host": "redacted.com",
      "accept-encoding": "gzip",
      "cf-ipcountry": "US",
      "x-forwarded-for": "66.102.6.238",
      "cf-ray": "2bba889f9fcb5011-DEN",
      "content-length": "1306",
      "cf-visitor": "{\"scheme\":\"https\"}",
      "accept": "*/*",
      "x-goog-channel-id": "cdn-channel-id-redacted",
      "x-goog-resource-state": "exists",
      "x-goog-message-number": "9748944617",
      "x-goog-resource-id": "-----resource-id------",
      "x-goog-resource-uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/cdn.redacted.com/o?alt=json",
      "x-goog-channel-token": "secret-token-redacted",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "user-agent": "APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)",
      "cf-connecting-ip": "66.102.6.238",
      "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
      "connection": "close"
    },
    "httpVersion": "1.1",
    "trailers": {},
    "version": "*",
    "timers": {
      "remapXFFheader": 32,
      "restifyCORSSimple": 16,
      "parseAccept": 120,
      "parseQueryString": 22,
      "gzip": 887,
      "checkIfMatch": 27,
      "checkIfNoneMatch": 22,
      "checkIfModified": 45,
      "checkIfUnmodified": 18,
      "remapContentType": 10,
      "readBody": 343,
      "parseBody": 57,
      "restifyLogger": 205,
      "attachAMQP": 19,
      "initContext": 12,
      "activateAccount": 542,
      "handeReact": 411,
      "responseContentType": 27,
      "gceWebhook": 304,
      "completeResumableUpload": 55245
    }
  },
  "res": {
    "statusCode": 202,
    "headers": {
      "content-encoding": "gzip",
      "content-type": "application/vnd.api+json"
    },
    "trailer": false
  },
  "err": null,
  "latency": 63,
  "_audit": true,
  "msg": "handled: 202",
  "time": "2016-07-01T14:26:33.645Z",
  "v": 0
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the [Reliable Delivery](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Reliable_Delivery) section of the documentation. In particular, I'll quote here:

> Object Change Notification will attempt to deliver notifications to
>   your application in a reliable way. However, be aware that
>   notifications can be delayed indefinitely, and timeliness is not
>   guaranteed.

Comment: I did see that, though it doesn't change the fact that for 6 months straight timing was near immediate and now it doesn't even get close to it. 1 hour delays for the past 3 days is somewhat of a norm. Therefore, I was hoping to get some more insight knowledge on the topic here.

Comment: Hi @Vitaly , I understand your frustration. Although the general policy is that notifications can be delayed indefinitely, we do strive to deliver them quickly. We are aware of the issue causing the delay and are working on resolving the issue. I will reply again here once the issue is resolved. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hi @Vitaly , the issue is resolved on our side. Latency should be back to normal.

Comment: this once again has become a problem and now it's extremely inconsistent. Can you take a look for notification delays on civic-meridian-130023 project? Literally a week ago the most time that would take before a notification is delivered is 2 seconds, now its easily 45 seconds. Is there any way to make this more reliable with GCS?

Comment: Hi @Vitaly, we recently launched a beta of cloud pubsub integration for GCS. Documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications). I suggest trying it out: I expect you'll find latency and reliability is much better. Let me know if you get a chance to try it.

Comment: I've added pubsub to my project, it indeed works much better. Still quite a pain in the ass to setup in between gsutil and consumption logic, and documentation is quite spread out. Specifically for the case where you would have multiple machines consuming one topic, it was very hard to find how the message distribution is performed. For instance, you have to create subscription once and then "get" its id for consumption, instead of "subscribing" with the same name, otherwise all of the subscriptions will have different backlogs & it would be like fanout exchange in rabbitmq

Comment: after further testing it seems that the delay is still there, but it largely depends on the size of the bucket. Example log - https://gist.github.com/AVVS/810df6ee2b8aa1f203f1654e72bc094c#file-log-json-L41. This is 1 minute after the file was uploaded, and when I do more tests I've seen it as long as 2 minutes after upload, but never as quick as on the small buckets. Can you help me with that?